# Mouse stops working when I try to minimize window in macOS

Tags: macos

I am getting a bizarre error on an earlier 2015 MacBook Air running macOS 10.15 (Catalina).

When I click on the yellow minimize button on an application I get a spinning beachball for a few seconds, then all mouse functionality on trackpad or USB wireless mouse ceases on that application.

This happened for both the Amazon music app and for Chrome. Inexplicably, when I select “Extensions” from the Chrome menu, I get all mouse functionality back until I select “minimize” again.

Also, the dock stays hidden even after pressing <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> and also when I go to System Preferences and uncheck “Hide the Dock.”

Answer (score 1):

First tests:-

- Try in another user account.
- Test in Safe mode [shift key at boot]

If you still get the same behaviour, then overlay the OS. This does not change any user files [though you should always have a backup for just in case] but checks & replaces system files.

- Boot to Recovery -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  - and select Reinstall macOS.

Comment: I booted in safe mode and tried to log into my account instead of the original user's account. Currently, I am able to minimize and I do not experience any issues.

Comment: That would tell me it's something installed **only** for one user… which is not easy to figure out.